# what is the content of post-receive.sample?

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I'm missing the hooks/post-receive.sample file that is allegedly just a short script. Would you please care to write me its content?

That was my question above, but stackoverflow did not accept it, maybe it was too short, so I add some more content.

Comment: Did you try a [search on the internet](https://github.com/defunkt/repo-in-a-repo/blob/master/lyndon.git/hooks/post-receive.sample)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All hooks in git are by default empty scripts, with a few comments describing what happens. You can simply create a script like below to find out what parameters the script is called with, and reverse-engineer the meaning of them:

```
#/bin/bash
echo $@
```

In case of the post-receive hook, it is the following, which comes from [the link](https://github.com/defunkt/repo-in-a-repo/blob/master/lyndon.git/hooks/post-receive.sample) @jurgemaister provided.

```
# The "post-receive" script is run after receive-pack has accepted a pack
# and the repository has been updated.  It is passed arguments in through
# stdin in the form
#  <oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
# For example:
#  aa453216d1b3e49e7f6f98441fa56946ddcd6a20 68f7abf4e6f922807889f52bc043ecd31b79f814 refs/heads/master
```

Your hook will obviously do something specific for you, so you have to write your own script there with the corresponding variables `$1` (oldrev), `$2` (newrev), and `$3` (refname).